# Kill downstream task depending on upstream task in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG in which I have 2 tasks.

```
t1=  PythonOperator(
    task_id='Check_Files_in_S3',
    provide_context=False,
    python_callable=checkFilesInS3,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

t2 =  PythonOperator(
    task_id='snowflakeLoad',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=snowflakeLoad,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

t1>>t2
```

First task Looks for files in S3 and if files are available, then task should be succesfull and data should be loaded to snowflake using the downstream task.

My requirement is if files are not available then task1 needs to send a mail then it should stop the downstream task(task2). Is there a way to achieve this something like returning false will fail the downstream task? also depends_on_past will not run the DAG if the earlier DAG run fails? or it don't run the downstream tasks if one of the task failed in the present run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple questions in there so let me break it down.

> Is there a way to achieve this something like returning false will fail the downstream task?

The usual way to wait for something to happen is to use a sensor (which inherit from the BaseSensorOperator) class. They are specialised for being low-resource consuming and easy to configure for sensing external objects/resources.
However, in your case it's a check and forget (don't retry if it's not there). Then you can stick with PythonOperator. You'd simply raise an exception and it would be seen as if the task failed, preventing the downstream task(t2 in your case) to run.

> also depends_on_past will not run the DAG if the earlier DAG run fails? or it don't run the downstream tasks if one of the task failed in the present run?

If we have your two tasks, assume we have two DAGRuns. One at point `x` in time and one at point `x + 1`. If you have `depends_on_past=True`, the run of task `t1` for `x + 1` will look at run `t1` at time `x` and will only start if that run was a success.
The same holds for `t2` of `x + 1` where it will check that task `t1` of `x + 1` completed and then check that `t2` of time `x` succeeded.

Comment: So T2 in X+1 run don't depends on T1 in X run. Also T2 of X+1 does not depends on T1 of X+1 run. Is that correct?

Comment: Sensors use case is when you want to wait for something to happen. The op use case isn't about waiting for the files to appear. The op mentioned that the use case is to stop downstream tasks and send email when files are not present.

Comment: A good point Elad. I didn't take that into the consideration. Thanks for rectifying that.

Comment: Yes `t2` in `x + 1` run don't check for the state of `t1` in `x`. That is automatically factored in by the fact that `t2` of `x` is depended on `t1` of `x` as `t2` is a downstream of `t1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can raise `AirflowSkipException` in `checkFilesInS3` when there are no files. This will cause downstream tasks to be skipped as well before raising the exception you can also send email.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.email import send_email


def checkFilesInS3(**kwargs):
    your_code
    if no_files: #Raise exception to make downstream tasks skip
        send_email(to="someone@somewhere.com, subject="task failed!"")
        raise AirflowSkipException("No files found!")


def snowflakeLoad(**kwargs):
    pass


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 23),

}
with DAG(dag_id='question',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=None,
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task')

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Check_Files_in_S3',
        python_callable=checkFilesInS3,
    )

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='snowflakeLoad',
        python_callable=snowflakeLoad,
    )

    start >> t1 >> t2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Elad. I don't want to mark the task as fail. So i'm using BranchPythonOperator depending on the files availability. If files are not available I'm picking the task to raise an  incident.

Comment: Skip is not fail. Tasks can be in SKIPPED status as part of normal ETL flow. Since there are no files to process then simply skip the tasks.